# Android Beacon Library - BLE beacons detecting is not working

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to detecting beacons with [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) in Android. I created a service which is running in background and detecting beacons.

The problem is that app is not detecting beacons when bluetooth is turned off. But if I turn on bluetooth is working properly. There is a really weird thing as well. If I turn off bluetooth again while app is running, it still continue detecting. It means that BLE detecting is working but only if I turn on bluetooth and turn it off again.

How can I enable BLE detecting? There is my implementation below. Do I miss something?

**Beacon Service class**

```
public class BeaconDiscoverer extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {
    private static final String TAG = BeaconDiscoverer.class.getSimpleName();
    private static BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private static Region region;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;

    public BeaconDiscoverer() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        region = new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null);
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

        configureBatterySaverMode();

        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void configureBatterySaverMode() {
        BeaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(getApplicationContext());

        // set the duration of the scan to be 5 seconds
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(Utility.convertToMilliseconds(2));
        // set the time between each scan to be 1 min (60 seconds)
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(Utility.convertToMilliseconds(25));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BeaconDiscoverer started up");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect");
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Beacon detected: " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " m. - " + firstBeacon.getBluetoothAddress());

                }
            }
        });

        startRanging();
    }

    public void stopRanging() {
        try {
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startRanging() {
        if (User.currentUser() == null)
            return;

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Application class**

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = App.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startService(new Intent(this, BeaconDiscoverer.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: I want to detect beacons when bluetooth is not turned off. I mean If user does not turn on bluetooth at least one time, ble detecting is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple answer: you must have Bluetooth enabled to detect beacons** with the library.  Beacons use Bluetooth LE to advertise their presence, and the Bluetooth radio must be on to hear the signals.

I cannot explain why you continue to detect beacons after turning off Bluetooth.  One possibility is that you just see them from memory cache for the library's brief scan cycle period before they disappear.  Another possibility is that the Android device is saying Bluetooth is off when you switch it off, but it is not really off.

The typical approach is to detect if Bluetooth is off when the app is launched, and prompt the user to turn it on.  There is sample code in the Reference Application that does this [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/MonitoringActivity.java#L107).

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought that we don't need to enable bluetooth after lollipop devices to detect beacons. I was just confused because my phone detect beacons after I turn off bluetooth. Anyway, I was also implemented warning the user to turn bluetooth on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void registerBoradcastReceiver() {
    IntentFilter stateChangeFilter = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    IntentFilter connectedFilter = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
//IntentFilter connectedFilter = new   IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    IntentFilter disConnectedFilter = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(stateChangeReceiver, stateChangeFilter);
    registerReceiver(stateChangeReceiver, connectedFilter);
    registerReceiver(stateChangeReceiver, disConnectedFilter);
}

    private BroadcastReceiver stateChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED == action) {
            startService;
        }
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED == action) {
            stopService;
        }
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED == action) {

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: can you provide some explanation?

Comment: Receive bluetooth Broadcast .